# How to retrieve all database names in a mongoDB cluster?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Ive looked through api reference, you can get database users, clusters, all clusters, collections, documents within a collection but there was nothing listed about getting the database names themselves.

How can this be done?

Comment: Use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/#dbcmd.listDatabases

Comment: thanks, if you want to create a code example with necessary setup in answer format ill choose it as answer @WernfriedDomscheit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view all databases, from mongo shell

`show dbs`

Or if you want your response to be structured as json

`db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } )`